# Add to a hashtable

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

I am trying to implement a hash table

Comment: *Can someone look over my private member [...]* -- giggle ;)

Comment: hashTable is an `item *`. `s` is not an item.

Comment: I apologise for that bad joke. On topic: you may want to improve the indentation of your code for enhanced readability.

Comment: Something is going wrong with all your edits (in this and other questions). First you ask detailed questions with code, then get replies and discuss them and then delete all the content except half a sentence. This makes the question meaningless unless readers rollback your edits. Please leave enough material so that new readers can understand what is going on! –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add a `const stock` value to your `item *` hashtable. If you need to add a stock to the table, make an `item` struct out of it first, or change the type of the hashtable.

Comment: Create a new `item` struct, and set its symbol, sharePrice, name, priceDate, and items to those of the stock. Or, make the hashtable a `stock*` instead of `item*` or something like that.

Comment: I assume you have a textbook? The information is probably in there. I don't want to write your homework for you. On the topic, are you taking this CS260 at PCC?

Comment: I did, but we had different assignments.